# xsl namespace from root copied to child node ,copy-namespaces="no" not working (xslt 3.0 version)

Tags: xslt, namespaces

The script which i'm trying with a source xml and the result is available in the below fiddle tool link

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRK/4

Source XML:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/rib/RibMessages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd">
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   <child xmlns="http://test.com">
       <element1>1</element1>
   </child>   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

XSL Script used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="copy-sans-namespaces" as="element()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ser-params" as="element()">
            <output:serialization-parameters xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
                <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes" />
            </output:serialization-parameters>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="serialize($copy-sans-namespaces, $ser-params)" />
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*:root|*:parent|*:parentdtl|*:outer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected OutPut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/rib/RibMessages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd">
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   &lt;child xmlns="http://test.com"&gt;
       &lt;element1&gt;1&lt;/element1&gt;
   &lt;/child&gt;   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

Instead i'm receiving the below result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/rib/RibMessages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   &lt;child xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;
       &lt;element1&gt;1&lt;/element1&gt;
   &lt;/child&gt;   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

Facing two issues in the XSL script,

1. XSL is including one of the namespace from root to its child while escaping.
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" , but this should not be included while escaping the `<child>` node but the original namespace of `<child>` node should be retained in the conversion.
2. The namespaces in the root is not all copied in the Result XML.
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd"
   is missed in the parent `<root>` node of resultant xml.

please share any pointers as i'm very new to XSLT.
XSL version is 3.0 and using SAXON 9.6 engine in the project which i'm working on.

Comment: Please include the relevant samples of XML and XSLT and wanted and current output in your question here on StackOverflow. It doesn't suffice to link to an online sample.

Comment: Hi Martin, Please see the question updated with the details .

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a quirk or bug in Saxon, I have asked on the Saxonica forum https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/8011, let's hear what they think. I am not sure how to work around it for your input case, you could try to push your element(s) through a different mode where you use `xsl:element` instead of `xsl:copy-of` to recreate element nodes, that way the namespaces should not be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the behaviour you get with Saxon 9.6 is a bug still present in Saxon 10.2, I enquired about it in https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/8011 which lead to the bug issue https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4793.

As a workaround, I guess you need to push your element through a node taking copies with `xsl:element`, avoiding namespace copying:

```
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="strip-in-scope-namespaces">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="copy-sans-namespaces" as="element()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="strip-in-scope-namespaces"/>
        </xsl:variable>
      
        <xsl:variable name="ser-params" as="element()">
            <output:serialization-parameters xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
                <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes" />
            </output:serialization-parameters>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="serialize($copy-sans-namespaces, $ser-params)" />
    </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRK/5

As for `xsi:schemaLocation` missing, that is an attribute you forgot to copy; use

```
   <xsl:template match="*:root|*:parent|*:parentdtl|*:outer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRK/6

Comment: Thank You Martin, This really helps.  One more clarification please. In the node <root> it did not copy all the name spaces xsi:schemalocation is not appearing in the resultant XML. Is this a bug or should anything needs to be changes in script.

Comment: @Prasanth, see the edit, you need to copy attributes through.

Comment: Thank You Martin, It worked really well in the project.